# How to answer grammatically ambiguous tricky questions

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, word-usage

Here are some examples :

1) The mangoes (will ripe/ripe/will ripen) over time said John.

2) The least considered in the latest Terrorist attacks (are/were/was) the innocent victims.

My choice for 1) would be:

- "ripe" if it is considered as a fact, so present tense is good choice.
- "will ripe" if it is considered as an opinion of John rather than a fact; the sentence is in the past tense, so past tense is good choice.

My choice for 2) would be:

- "were" if it is in newspaper article and it describes a past event.
- "are" if it is live reporting of a statement.

I have checked them in [this checker](http://ed.grammarly.com/editor/view/?f=1), and results show that all of the options are correct.

**EDIT1** :And what about:

This (calls/calls for/calls against) a treat.

Uprooting plants (is/are/have been/was) like uprooting your life.

Also please suggest most critical points to consider if possible while answering such questions and apologies for not following the standards for asking the question, i am a newbie so i am getting acquainted with it.But I have done research for these questions and did not get the answer , that's why asked here.

Comment: Your first two grammarly-checked options are wrong: "The mangoes will ripen over time" is the only correct option. For your second example, I wouldn't use 'were'.  The question states 'latest attacks' for a reason - to eliminate the past tense option. The latest attacks *could* be three months ago, but it is unlikely.

Comment: Too Localised/General Reference

Comment: "Uprooting plants" cannot be "are" or "have been" because it is singular. Note the key word is "uprooting", a verb functioning as a noun. Of course "plants" is plural, but it is not the plants that are doing something here, but the uprooting. Most likely you would use "is", because this sounds like a general philosophical statement. If you were talking about one particular incident you might use "was", like if someone had just told you about a time he uprooted plants, and you replied, "Yes, uprooting plants was like" etc.

Answer (score 9):

*Ripe* isn't a verb; *ripen* is. You need a verb there in order for the sentence to be grammatical. So for 1, you should have:

> "The mangoes **will ripen** over time," said John.

Now for 2, either *are* or *were* would make grammatical sense.  The singular *was* does not agree with the plural subject *victims*.  But between *are* (present tense) and *were* (past), either would work because the time in question could be in the past or in the relative present ("in the latest terrorist attacks"):

> The least considered in the latest terrorist attacks **were** the innocent victims.
>
> *or*
>
> The least considered in the latest terrorist attacks **are** the innocent victims.

Comment: *This calls for a treat* is correct.  The other two don't make sense.  *Calls for* is a phrasal verb meaning *is an appropriate occasion for*.

Comment: @gauravsharma It would be better if you took some time and considered your questions prior to posting them, so that all of your question could be addressed at once. Asking multiple questions across comments will not be helpful to future readers, and makes it hard to answer you.

Comment: Seems like there is an ambiguity between views of @daniel and roaring-fish...which one is most appropriate option plz suggest..i am just a newbie ...

Comment: Both *are* and *were* are OK; they both make sense.  As Roaring Fish says, though, *are* is probably indicated because the sentence sounds a lot like it's talking about the present.

Comment: anyways thanks @Danielδ for your time, answer and views

Comment: also thanks @roaring-fish for your views